# unordered_map to find indices of an array

Tags: c++, performance, set, unordered-map

I want to find indices of a set efficiently. I am using unordered_map and making the inverse map like this

```
std::unordered_map <int, int> myHash (size); 
Int i = 0;
for (it = someSet.begin(); it != someSet.end(); it++)
{
    myHash.insert({*it , i++});
 }
```

It works but it is not efficient. I did this so anytime I need the indices I could access them O(1). Performance analysis is showing me that this part became hotspot of my code.

VTune tells me that `new` operator is my hotspot. I guess something is happening inside the unordered_map.
It seems to me that this case should be handled efficiently. I couldn't find a good way yet. Is there a better solution? a correct constructor?
Maybe I should pass more info to the constructor. I looked up the initialize list but it is not exactly what I want.

Update: Let me add some more information. The set is not that important; I save the set in to an array (sorted). Later I need to find the index of the values which are unique. I can do it in logn but it is not fast enough. It is why I decided to use a hash. The size of the set (columns of submatrix) doesn't change after this point.

It arise from sparse matrix computation which I need to find index of submatrices in a bigger matrix. Therefore the size and the pattern of the look ups is depend on the input matrix. It works reasonable on smaller problems. I could use a lookup table but while I am planning to do it in parallel the lookup table for each thread can be expensive. I have the exact size of hash in the time of creation. I thought by sending it to the constructor it stops reallocating. I really don't understand why it is reallocating this much.

Comment: `Int`? You mean `int`?

Comment: How many elements are you converting? How many lookups are you doing? The expense of creating a look-up table may exceed any savings you get, so it might be a false optimization. There's some threshold value where the number of elements > *N* and the number of lookups > *M* yields positive results, but below that is actually a net negative.

Comment: @tadman I just copied my code and simplified it here. Forgot to change this part. Not  important anyway. Int is long int

Comment: @tadman It is a part of larger project. it is working fine for small input sizes but doesn't work good when the size grows

Comment: You'll need to explore what the pay-off of this strategy is as I explained earlier. I'd write a wrapper class around this thing that does the optimization *if* it thinks it'll be productive, and just does it the default way otherwise. That makes it easier to tune.

Comment: Why would you want an index of a *set* element? Even when you have it, accessing the element (using `std::distance()` is O(n).

Comment: @Eugene it is a part of a larger project. I store the set in an array eventually.

Comment: It does not seem to make sense in any size project. If you are asking about efficiency, then you also need to explain why you need the index. Note that finding the element in the original set is faster: it is O(log(n)), while by using your index it is O(n).

Comment: @Eugene hash makes O (long) to O(1). I don’t understand what O(n) is coming from

Comment: Yes, accessing unordered map to get the index is O(1). I just can't imagine a situation when having the index will be useful for anything. In my over 20 years of C++ experience, I never felt a need to take an index of a set element (storing an iterator instead could be useful). So I am asking to give an example how you would use the index, and what speed advantage it gets.

Comment: O(n) is coming from using `std::distance()`. Where else would you use the index?

Comment: Unless you have a perfect hash you are not guaranteed to get O(1), and in worst case you get O(N).

Comment: It's unclear to me what value is the index of each value in a set, in iteration order. There is no method of a set to return the value with the given index. This looks like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @Eugene making index lookup makes perfect sense as iterator would get invalidated upon a resize.

Comment: @ALX23z std::set does invalidate on resize, it doesn't have a resize ...

Comment: The issue is most likely due to the size of the array. Making lookup too large surely causes issues due to an overly large fragmented allocations. Consider an algorithmic work around for your project. Try to find the indices in some other way or utilize `pmr` for allocations in the `unordered_map`. If you just add elements, perhaps you could just make a large reservation and just put the elements ano after another

Comment: @Surt while he wrote `SomeSet` he said that he stored indices of an **array**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `std::unordered_map`, mainly implemented as a list of vectors, is extremely cache-unfriendly, and will perform especially poorly with small keys/values (like `int,int` in your case), not to mention requiring tons of (re-)allocations.

As an alternative you can try a third-party hash map implementing [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) with [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) (a mouthful, but the underlying structure is simply a vector, i.e. much more cache-friendly). For example, Google's [`dense_hash_map`](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_map.html) or this: [`flat_hash_map`](https://probablydance.com/2017/02/26/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable/). Both can be used as a drop-in replacement for `unordered_map`, and  only additionally require to designate one `int` value as the "empty" key.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` doesn’t have any issues with reallocations. Perhaps the lookup table requires such but not the basic elements. It does makes tons allocations though so it is ill advised for large hashes.

Comment: I end up implementing my own hash using linear probing. It is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

std::unordered_map<int, int> is often implemented as if it was

```
std::vector<std::list<std::par<int, int>>>
```

Which causes a lot of allocations and deallocations of each node, each (de-)allocation is using a lock which causes contention.

You can help it a bit by using emplace instead of insert, or you can jump out in the fantastic new world of pmr allocators. If your creation and destruction of the pmr::unordered_map is single threaded you should be able to get a lot of extra performance out of it. See Jason Turners [C++ Weekly - Ep 222 - 3.5x Faster Standard Containers With PMR!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6A7cKFXjY0), his example is a bit on the small side but you can get the general idea.

Comment: The description of the issue is correct, but I'm not too sure PMR is the best recommendation.  Google's hash tables are widely used, and there are other faster options - https://probablydance.com/2017/02/26/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable/ is a good read.